# DynamoDB data validation during Query when using V2 Enhanced SDK

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamodb-enhanced-client

We are reading from DynamoDB table and want to use the Java V2 Enhanced SDK.  We are able to build and run the code, but we are getting errors when some attributes are returning the wrong type.  For example, an attribute which should store a Long has either an empty string (`""`) or is empty (`<empty>`).  The result is the SDK is throwing an exception:

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "<empty>"`

Is there a way to handle these errors?

Here is the query code:

```
DynamoDbTable<MyRecord> myTable = enhancedClient.table(TABLE_NAME, MySchema);

queryConditional = QueryConditional
        .keyEqualTo(Key.builder()
                .partitionValue(partKeyValue)
                .sortValue     (sortKeyValue)
                .build());

List<T> results = myTable.query(r -> r.queryConditional(queryConditional))
        .items()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And the schema definition looks like this:

```
StaticTableSchema<MyRecord> MySchema = TableSchema.builder(MyRecord.class)
        .newItemSupplier(MyRecord::new)
        .addAttribute(Integer.class,     a -> a.name("ID")
                .getter(MyRecord::getID)
                .setter(MyRecord::setID)
                .tags(primaryPartitionKey()))
        .addAttribute(String.class,      a -> a.name("ClientID")
                .getter(MyRecord::getClientID)
                .setter(MyRecord::setClientID)
                .tags(primarySortKey()))
        ...
        .build();
```

I assume that there is some extra code that I can add to the TableSchema definition that allow some data validation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Table level resource client which acts as a mapper between your java class object and your table. For this you work you should have a strict class definition, which means attributes which are Longs should not also contain string values, or any other non number values.

You can overcome this a number of ways:

1. Use a low level client without mappings
2. Use an attribute converter class and handle the deserialization of those attributes which are containing multiple data types.
3. Clean your table so it does not contain corrupted data.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Unfortunately, one does not always get to control table data as strongly as one would like.  And even so, there are merits to making table access method more robust.

Answer (score -1):

Following the recommendations of @LeeHannigan I looked into the converter-classes.  I also spoke with AWS support and they came to the same conclusion.  Converter-classes look powerful but I wish there was some sample code that explains the infrastructure.  Here is the documentation that I could find: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverted.html) and [here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/mapper/annotations/DynamoDbAttribute.html).

On a lark, I experimented with treating the table data as string versions of the long-numbers and using the getter/setter methods to handle conversions.  Much to my surprise this worked.  It turns out that "Number" attributes, when they are made "`<empty>`" change type to a String.  And, also, even when they are `Number` types they can still be returned as a string object.  The following handled the scenario when some attributes were empty or empty strings:

```
@DynamoDbBean
public final class MyRecord{

    private long myLongNumber = 0;

    public String getMyLongNumber() {
        return String.valueOf(myLongNumber);
    }

    public void setMyLongNumber(String myLongNumber) {
        this.myLongNumber = NumberUtils.toInt(myLongNumber, 0);
    }
```

And

```
StaticTableSchema<MyRecord> MySchema = TableSchema.builder(MyRecord.class)
        .newItemSupplier(MyRecord::new)
        ...
        .addAttribute(String.class, a -> a.name("myLongNumber")
           .getter(MyRecord::getMyLongNumber)
           .setter(MyRecord::setMyLongNumber))
```